# Proof verification: almost linear map is injective iff the kernel only contains zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, linear-transformations

$f:V\to W$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-$\mathbb{C}$-linear map between a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $V$ and a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $W$ if
$$
f(av+bw)=af(v)+bf(w):=(a+i0)f(v)+(b+i0)f(w)
$$
for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $v,w\in V$.

> Theorem: A $\mathbb{R}$-$\mathbb{C}$-linear map is injective iff the kernel only contains zero.

*Proof:*
 Assume that $f$ is injective and note that
    \begin{align*}
 f(\mathbf{0})= f(0\cdot \mathbf{0}) = 0f(\mathbf{0}):=(0+i0)f(\mathbf{0}) = \mathbf{0},
 \end{align*}
    proving that $\mathbf{0}\in \mathrm{ker}(f):=\{v\in V: f(v)=\mathbf{0}\}$, and by injectivity of $f$ we have that $\mathrm{ker}(f)$ must be a singleton, hence $\mathrm{ker}(f)=\{\mathbf{0}\}$. Conversely assume that $\mathrm{ker}(f)=\{\mathbf{0}\}$ and consider any two elements $v_1,v_2\in V$ such that $f(v_1)=f(v_2)$. Then $f(v_1-v_2)=f(v_1)-f(v_2)=\mathbf{0}$, implying that $v_1-v_2\in \mathrm{ker}(f)$, but this must entail that $v_1-v_2=\mathbf{0}\iff v_1=v_2$, since $\mathrm{ker}(f)=\{\mathbf{0}\}$.

QED.

This proof is a straight forward replication of the true linear case, but I can't find any problems with it in this case. Am i correct that I can extend the well known theorem, to what i defined as $\mathbb{R}$-$\mathbb{C}$-linear maps above?

Comment: The RHS of the first equation confuses me. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: As $W$ is a complex vector space, the multiplication of a real scalar, must formally be understood as the scalar multiplication with complex number.

Comment: But I am missing $w$ and $b$?

Comment: my bad, its missing $f(w)$. Thanks.

Comment: So just set $a=b=1$ and then it is a homorphism of abelian groups and you can use the corresponding result for those?

Comment: I have never had courses in Algebra, so that approach is beyond my comprehension. Thanks anyways.

Comment: The basic point is you can drop $a$ and $b$ in this proof. (I.e. set them to $1$). So you don't need the scalar multiplication in this proof just the addition. Thus your proof is also valid for (abelian) groups and group homomorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

Here is another reason it should work out the same: The vectors in a complex vector space also form a real vector space under vector addition and scalar multiplication by reals. Your "almost linear" maps are then linear maps to this corresponding real vector space. Since you already have this result for linear maps between real vector spaces, it still holds here.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Does the restriction of scalar space have a name in the litterature- just so that i can read up on it.

Comment: @Martin, there's not much to read up on in the general case. You'll just see phrases like "$V$ considered as a vector space over $k$". For example, "$\mathbb R$ considered as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$." For this special case, some related reading can be found under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_structure#Vector_space